# gcloud recommendations for a GCP instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am looking for a way to see if I can print the recommendations for a GCP instance using gcloud cli or any of the available Google API so far no luck.

Comment: what kind of recommendations ?

Comment: Hi @howie, if you if see Google cloud console UI we see a recommendation for an instance to be update with few CPU's are few gig ram to be added. Just want to see if we can get the same information from cli.

Comment: No such cli and api~

Comment: Actually, there is a recommendations API. It is not public yet. You will have to wait until its release.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to [Specifying a Minimum CPU Platform for VM Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/specify-min-cpu-platform) feature or to the gcloud command ([link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-min-cpu-platform)):

```
$ gcloud alpha compute instances set-min-cpu-platform
```

You can print the official documentation added in the above links.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it's not what I was looking for. In the column section of compute engine we can see a column called recommendations. I want to print/use it by using cli tools like gcloud or any of the available Google API's.

Comment: The [Monitoring Agent](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/apply-sizing-recommendations-for-instances#using_the_monitoring_agent_for_more_precise_recommendations) gives you recommendations and you can use it with gcloud command.